# Script error login visual studio DefaultLogin_PCore.js

Tags: visual-studio, account

I have this error when trying to start my account in visual studio, any solution?

https://auth.gfx.ms/16.000.26754.00/DefaultLogin_PCore.js[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OtRZy.png)

Answer (score 0):

I hit the same issue.  I worked through this by clicking through the dialogs and allowing it to continue running scripts.  After the script failures were done I was left with a white dialog.  I then pressed F5 to refresh the browser page in the dialog and it showed me the box to enter my password and then let me in.

Comment: This isn't a solution, you could have put this into a comment.